# Gdal vsicurl not working

Tags: python, gdal, landsat

I'm currently using gdal version 1.11.2 (also tested this on 2.0.0) to open AWS Landsat-8 data directly from its url.

If I manually test the link in the browser, it works. If I use /vsicurl/ the returned variable is None.

```
from osgeo import gdal

url = 'http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B5.TIF'

src = gdal.Open('/vsicurl/%s' %(url))

print src
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by downgrading gdal to 1.10.1.

Would be nice to know why /vsicurl/ isnt working in more recent versions of gdal, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: There is something about AWS in GDAL 2.1 release news: "/vsicurl/: by default do not use HEAD request when detecting a AWS S3 signed
URL". Perhaps you should try 2.1 and report the problem to gdal-dev mailing list if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL 2.1-dev seems to make a connection:

```
gdalinfo http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.co
m/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B5.TIF
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: none associated
Size is 7621, 7791
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 45N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",87],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32645"]]
Origin = (381885.000000000000000,2512815.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  381885.000, 2512815.000) ( 85d50'59.56"E, 22d43' 6.56"N)
Lower Left  (  381885.000, 2279085.000) ( 85d51'59.39"E, 20d36'25.83"N)
Upper Right (  610515.000, 2512815.000) ( 88d 4'34.07"E, 22d43' 8.41"N)
Lower Right (  610515.000, 2279085.000) ( 88d 3'38.09"E, 20d36'27.50"N)
Center      (  496200.000, 2395950.000) ( 86d57'47.78"E, 21d40' 0.56"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```