# GPX driver not working with vsicurl

Tags: gdal, ogr, gpx

I want to access a couple of *GPX* files online to extract the tracks and waypoints for some feature classes.  When I download the files, `ogrinfo` (version 2.4.1 on a Mac)works fine.

```
ogrinfo /Users/ianhorn/Downloads/KAT_Motorcycle.gpx 
INFO: Open of `/Users/ianhorn/Downloads/KAT_Motorcycle.gpx'
      using driver `GPX' successful.
1: waypoints (Point)
2: routes (Line String)
3: tracks (Multi Line String)
4: route_points (Point)
5: track_points (Point)
```

However, I would prefer to just grab the URL and process that way using `vsicurl`, but ogr spits out an error saying it cannot open the datasource with the driver.

```
ogrinfo /vsicurl/http://annessky.net/kat/gpx/KAT_Motorcycle.gpx  
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/vsicurl/http://annessky.net/kat/gpx/KAT_Motorcycle.gpx' with the following drivers.
```

Is it not possible to do this?

Update.  Solution provided by @Maptastik using python, https://repl.it/@maptastik/katmotorcyclegpxdownload

Comment: what version of gdal?  related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195992/gdal-vsicurl-not-working

Comment: version 2.4.1 on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was looking for that link and couldn't remember where. I saw it.

Comment: Turns out, files were the issue, not `vsicurl`.  @maptastick came up with a solution using python to open a browser session to read the file, the write it locally.