# Getting 404 response while fetching Landsat-8 data from AWS S3

Tags: landsat-8, amazon-web-services

I am trying to fetch Landsat-8 satellite data from AWS S3 and for getting details, I am using gdalinfo command:

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/c1/L8/144/048/LC08_L1TP_144048_20140315_20170425_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_144048_20140315_20170425_01_T1_B4.TIF
```

But getting this response:

```
ERROR 11: HTTP response code: 404
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/vsicurl/https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/c1/L8/144/048/LC08_L1TP_144048_20140315_20170425_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_144048_20140315_20170425_01_T1_B4.TIF'.
```

I am getting this error recently. This used to work till last month.

Comment: related (maybe the gdal version?) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195992/gdal-vsicurl-not-working

Comment: It should not be related to gdal version as this command used to work till last month in the same environment.

Comment: Is Landsat-8 collection 1 data still available through AWS S3?

Answer (score 3):

According to file at: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/

The list of available scenes can be found in https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/scene_list.gz

Looking at that file:

```
entityId,acquisitionDate,cloudCover,processingLevel,path,row,min_lat,min_lon,max_lat,max_lon,download_url
LC80101172015002LGN00,2015-01-02 15:49:05.571384,80.81,L1GT,10,117,-79.09923,-139.66082,-77.7544,-125.09297,https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/L8/010/117/LC80101172015002LGN00/index.html
LC80260392015002LGN00,2015-01-02 16:56:51.399666,90.84,L1GT,26,39,29.23106,-97.48576,31.36421,-95.16029,https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/L8/026/039/LC80260392015002LGN00/index.html
...
```

and following one of the download_urls we get an error:

```
...
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
...
```

Which according to https://itecnote.com/tecnote/r-amazon-s3-exception-the-specified-key-does-not-exist/ means that the `file does not exist up within the S3 bucket.`

So it's not your code it's an issue with the server; whether that's an oversight or deliberate is a question for the server administrator.

You can contact them, I think, through https://registry.opendata.aws/usgs-landsat/index.html