# Public AWS URL to Landsat-8 images - error 404

Tags: python, landsat, amazon-web-services

I'm not the only one having trouble downloading Landsat images from aws server using a URL like this: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/L8/017/008/LC80170082015211LGN00/index.html

As in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426678/getting-404-response-while-fetching-landsat-8-data-from-aws-s3), I obtain a 404 error using `request` module with Python.

Are the Landsat images still available on AWS ?

Comment: Is there an official Landsat page giving links to these images? Or someone else? Where did you get this URL from?

Comment: @Spacedman it looks like this is official ~ https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/start-using-landsat-on-aws/

Comment: YEs, I found it on the AWS pages. in the page mentioned by @nmtoken, you can also find this url http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/003/017/LC80030172015001LGN00/index.html that leads to a xml file with no content. I wonder if Amazon would have removed the direct access to the data through this url.

Comment: You need to speak to the data providers, USGS, about whether this is an error, or oversight,  There is a contact form at: https://registry.opendata.aws/usgs-landsat/index.html